# How to solve the equation, $(x+y)(y+z)(x+z) = 13xyz$ for $x,y,z \in Z$.

Tags: contest-math, diophantine-equations

How to find all **integer** solutions (that is, $x,y,z \in Z$) to equation:

$$(x + y)(y + z)(x + z) = 13xyz$$

It is known that there are zero-value solutions, but how to find non-zero ones? Could anyone give some tips?

---

More updates:

It is hard to find *all* non-zero integer resolutions, however,
if we **assume**: $$\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x,z)=\gcd(y,z)=1$$

it is very simple.

$ 13xyz = (x + y)(y + z)(x + z) = (x + y)(xy + xz + yz + z^2) = (x + y)[(xy + xz + yz) + z^2]  = (x + y)(xy + xz + yz) + (x + y)z^2 = (x + y)(xy + xz + yz) + z(xz + yz) = (x + y)(xy + xz + yz) + z(xy +xz+yz) - xyz = (x + y + z)(xy + xz + yz) - xyz \iff (x + y + z)(xy + xz + yz) = 14xyz \implies xyz | (x + y + z)(xy + xz + yz) \\
Then \ (x,y)=(x,z)=1 \implies (x,yz)=1 \implies (x,xy + xz + yz)=1 \
Similarly, \ (y,xy + xz + yz) = (z,xy + xz + yz) = 1 \implies (xyz,xy + xz + yz) = 1 \ but \ xyz | (x + y + z)(xy + xz + yz), \ then \ xyz |(x + y + z) \implies |xyz| \le |x + y + z| \ assume \ |x| \le |y| \le |z|, \ then |x|.|y|.|z| \le |x + y + z| \le 3|z|  \implies |x|.|y| \le 3$

So ${x, y} \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3\} $ then we can enumerate the solutions.

Comment: Let $a = kx$, $b= ky$ and $c = kz, \ k \in \Bbb Z_* $ then $a,b$ and $c$ would satisfy the equation given. So I guess it has infinitely many solutions. Am I wrong ?

Comment: A trivial solution is $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: Infinitely many because if $x=0,y=0$ $z$ can take any value and $x=0,z=0$ again the same for $y$ goes on...

Comment: By @A---B's observation (=homogeneity) this is equivalent to finding the rational solutions when $z=1$ (together with the bunch of uninteresting solutions with $z=0$). The resulting equation
$$0=(x+y)(y+1)(x+1)-13xy$$
is a cubic. An elliptic curve. Finding all the rational points may be taxing.

Comment: Does any none-zero solutions exist?

Comment: @A---B Yes, you are right~ but how to find any one of the none-zero solutions?

Comment: Yes, with $z=1,x=3/10$ there are rational solutions $(x,y,1)=(3/10,1/5,1)$ and $(3/10,3/2,1)$ giving rise to integer solutions $(x,y,z)=(3,2,10)$ and $(3,15,10)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen hello, after you've plotted $z=1$ how did you proceed on solving the equations?

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın My faithful silicon aide found those solutions. I was lucky to look for multiples of $1/10$. I don't know if there are others.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well:) Luck is important, I wish there was a classical way to solve these. Thank you:)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless I made a mistake the curve $(x+y)(x+1)(y+1)=13xy$ is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve in short Weierstrass form
$$v^2=u^3-\frac{11209}{48}u+\frac{1185157}{864}.$$ I'm no longer as optimistic about using this :-). Of course, we can use elliptic curve point doubling/addition idea in the original coordinates. That will have to wait for another day.

Comment: @Deniz Using the chord-tangent method on the original projective (elliptic) curve reveals that the solutions $P_1=[x:y:z]=[2:3:10]$ and $P_2=[x:y:z]=[3:10:15]$ are gotten from each other because they are collinear with a trivial solution $P_3=[0:1:0]$. Using the tangent at either $P_1$ or $P_2$ leads to another (primitive) solution
$$[-3619: 14664: 715].$$ Unless there is some residual interest in this I probably won't bother going on. Point addition/doubling on an elliptic curve may quickly lead to uncomfortably large coefficients.

Comment: To wit, using the tangent at the point $[-3619: 14664: 715]$ leads to the (primitive) solution :-)
$$[x:y:z]=[-13030716467024711: 196932807438576: -164522506539145] $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an 1995 Romanian olypiad training exercise, see [here](http://petermc.net/maths/olympiad/diophantine.pdf), number $10$: 
$$
(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)=txyz.
$$
It has solutions available (search for a link!). To exclude infinitely many "trivial" solutions (and others), one assumes there that $(x,y)=(x,z)=(y,z)=1$.
Here we do not need to assume this. It makes sense, though, to assume that the
solution is primitive, i.e., that $gcd(x,y,z)=1$.
 A primitive solution, for $t=13$ is for example $(x,y,z)=(3,2,10)$, see Jyrki's comment.
It produces infinitely many solutions (non-primitive) $(2k,3k,10k)$ for all $k$.

Edit: Without pairwise coprime $x,y,z$ it is nontrivial to find all solution. We need to use techniques from algebraic number theory for such Diophantine equations, e.g. for plane algebraic curves and rational points on it.

Comment: What does trivial exactly mean? For instance is my comment about $(x,y,z)$ being infinitely many, is this a trivial or non-trivial thing?

Comment: And we have also come to the conclusion that $(x,y,z)$ are **not** infinitely many, am I right?

Comment: @DenizTunaYalçın There **are** infinitely many, right?

Comment: Yes, that is also what I think but I am not very well accustomed to this topic and I baffled about The trivial part what does it exactly mean. I wanted to clarify it for myself. Thank you:)

Comment: Yes, I was not too clear: by "trivial" I mean that if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, we obtain trivially all multiples $(ka,kb,kc)$.

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde, but my problem didn't mention the constraint: $(x,y)=(x,z)=(y,z)=1$. However, it seems very hard to find all solutions without this constraint.