# Simplify the polynomial $xy(x+y)+(x+y)+(x+y)^2=13xy$ to the form $y^2=4x^3-g_{2}x-g_{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, elliptic-curves

> I try to simplify a polynomial to the form: $y^2=4x^3-g_{2}x-g_{3}$, which is the elliptic curves. And the polynomial is $xy(x+y)+(x+y)+(x+y)^2=13xy$.

I try to let the $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, then I get the $u^3-uv^2+4u-9u^2+13v^2=0$. But how to get ahead?

Comment: Are $g_2,g_3$ constants?  It seems odd to assume this can be done.

Comment: You want to write the cubic as $Y^2=4X^3-g_2X-g_3$ in a *different* system of coordinates. For the procedure, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1352408/62967

Comment: For some reason this reminds me of [this older contest problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2420098/11619), but I don't think it's the same. May be the appearance of 13 fooled me? Anyway, there are algorithms for bringing a smooth cubic into a Weierstrass form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that you have stated the problem correctly? As currently stated

$$ xy(x+y)+(x+y)+(x+y)^2=13xy $$

can be rewritten

\begin{eqnarray}
x^2y+xy^2+x+y+x^2+2xy+y^2&=&13xy\\
y^2(x+1)+y(x^2-11x+1)+x&=&0\\
y(x^2-11x+1)&=&-[y^2(x+1)+x]\\
y^2(x^2-11x+1)^2&=&[y^2(x+1)+x]^2
\end{eqnarray}
So if there exist constants $g_3,\,g_2$ such that
$$y^2=4x^3-g_{2}x-g_{3}$$

then

$$ (4x^3-g_{2}x-g_{3})(x^2-11x+1)^2=[(4x^3-g_{2}x-g_{3})(x+1)+x]^2 $$

This will resolve in an eighth degree polynomial equation of the form

$$ 16x^8-4x^7+P_6(x,g_2,g_3)=0 $$

Where $P_6$ is a degree six polynomial whose cofficients are function of $g_3,\,g_2$. But the coefficients of $x^8$ and $x^7$ are independent of the values of $g_3,\,g_2$.

So no constant values of $g_3,\,g_2$ can result in a solution for $x\ne0$.

Thus there cannot be values of $g_3,\,g_2$ for which $y^2=4x^3-g_{2}x-g_{3}$.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question which was not clear enough. The $x,y$ in the two equations are **not** the same. The question is to transform the given elliptic curve into short  Weierstrass form.

Comment: So OP intended the second equation as $Y^2=4X^3-g_{2}X-g_{3}$.

Comment: @Somos Yes, you are right!

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes, I want to get the Weiestrass form.

Answer (score 2):

Most working mathematicians would use a computer program for this computation. [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) works well, and is [available at no charge in all US universities](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/simons_details). Below is the computation in Magma. Note that Magma requires the use of projective coordinates. To convert from projective to affine, just set $Z=1$.

```
> P2<X,Y,Z> := ProjectiveSpace(Rationals(),2);
> C := Curve(P2, X*Y*(X+Y) + (X+Y)*Z^2 + (X+Y)^2*Z - 13*X*Y*Z);
> pt := C![0,0,1];
> EllipticCurve(C,pt);  
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 121*x^2 + 1144*x + 2704 over Rational Field
Mapping from: CrvPln: C to Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 121*x^2 + 1144*x + 2704 over Rational Field
with equations : 
52*X*Z
-52*X^2 - 52*X*Y + 572*X*Z - 104*Y*Z - 104*Z^2
-X^2 - X*Y
```

What all of the above means is that the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + 121x^2 + 1144x + 2704$ under the substitutions
\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{52 X}{-X^2 - X Y} = \frac{52}{-X-Y}\\
y &= \frac{-52X^2 - 52XY + 572X - 104Y - 104}{-X^2 - X Y}
\end{align*}
yields, after some simplification,
$$
\frac{10816 (X + Y + 1)(XY(X+Y) + (X+Y) + (X+Y)^2 - 13XY)}{X^2(X+Y)^3} = 0,
$$
which is equivalent to your original curve (look in the numerator of the fraction above).

The elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + 121x^2 + 1144x + 2704$ isn't quite in the form that you want. Converting it into the form that you want is an easy exercise.

[Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) (an open-source alternative to Magma) also works, but less well. It returns enormous equations:

```
sage: R.<x,y> = QQ[]
sage: cubic = x*y*(x+y) + (x+y) + (x+y)^2 - 13*x*y
sage: EllipticCurve(WeierstrassForm(cubic))
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + (-11209/48)*x + 1185157/864 over Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y over Rational Field
sage: WeierstrassForm(cubic,transformation=True)
(18421/8748*x^6*y^6 - 2873/1458*x^6*y^5 - 2873/1458*x^5*y^6 + 1692157/69984*x^6*y^4 + 1124317/34992*x^5*y^5 + 1692157/69984*x^4*y^6 + 14351/1296*x^6*y^3 - 5844665/17496*x^5*y^4 - 5844665/17496*x^4*y^5 + 14351/1296*x^3*y^6 + 1692157/69984*x^6*y^2 - 5844665/17496*x^5*y^3 + 150149899/69984*x^4*y^4 - 5844665/17496*x^3*y^5 + 1692157/69984*x^2*y^6 - 2873/1458*x^6*y + 1124317/34992*x^5*y^2 - 5844665/17496*x^4*y^3 - 5844665/17496*x^3*y^4 + 1124317/34992*x^2*y^5 - 2873/1458*x*y^6 + 18421/8748*x^6 - 2873/1458*x^5*y + 1692157/69984*x^4*y^2 + 14351/1296*x^3*y^3 + 1692157/69984*x^2*y^4 - 2873/1458*x*y^5 + 18421/8748*y^6,
15379/6561*x^9*y^8 - 15379/6561*x^8*y^9 - 15379/729*x^9*y^7 + 15379/729*x^7*y^9 + 1491763/19683*x^9*y^6 - 61516/6561*x^8*y^7 + 61516/6561*x^7*y^8 - 1491763/19683*x^6*y^9 - 353717/6561*x^9*y^5 - 61516/2187*x^8*y^6 + 61516/2187*x^6*y^8 + 353717/6561*x^5*y^9 + 353717/6561*x^9*y^4 + 76895/6561*x^7*y^6 - 76895/6561*x^6*y^7 - 353717/6561*x^4*y^9 - 1491763/19683*x^9*y^3 + 61516/2187*x^8*y^4 - 76895/6561*x^7*y^5 + 76895/6561*x^5*y^7 - 61516/2187*x^4*y^8 + 1491763/19683*x^3*y^9 + 15379/729*x^9*y^2 + 61516/6561*x^8*y^3 + 76895/6561*x^6*y^5 - 76895/6561*x^5*y^6 - 61516/6561*x^3*y^8 - 15379/729*x^2*y^9 - 15379/6561*x^9*y - 61516/6561*x^7*y^3 - 61516/2187*x^6*y^4 + 61516/2187*x^4*y^6 + 61516/6561*x^3*y^7 + 15379/6561*x*y^9 + 15379/6561*x^8*y - 15379/729*x^7*y^2 + 1491763/19683*x^6*y^3 - 353717/6561*x^5*y^4 + 353717/6561*x^4*y^5 - 1491763/19683*x^3*y^6 + 15379/729*x^2*y^7 - 15379/6561*x*y^8,
-13/27*x^3*y^3 + 121/108*x^3*y^2 + 121/108*x^2*y^3 + 121/108*x^3*y - 1175/108*x^2*y^2 + 121/108*x*y^3 - 13/27*x^3 + 121/108*x^2*y + 121/108*x*y^2 - 13/27*y^3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a good start but there was a complication you did not anticipate.
The homogeneous version of your equation is:
$\, 0 = -W X Y Z + (X+Y)(X+Z)(Y+Z), \,$ where $\, W=13 \,$ is a constant. Now substitute $\, X = 1 + c_3 x + \sqrt{c_1} y, $
$\, Y = 1 + c_3 x - \sqrt{c_1} y, $ $\, Z = 2 x + c_2, \,$
where $\,c_1,c_2,c_3 \,$ depend on $\,W.\,$ After the substitutions, we eliminate the $\, x y^2 \,$ term with $\, c_3 = W. \,$
We eliminate the $\,x^2\,$ term with
$\, c_2 = (2W^2 +16W + 8)/(W^3 - 4W^2 - 8W). \,$ Now the coefficients of $\,y^2\,$ and of $\,x^3\,$ needs adjustment to get the final form. Let $\, c_1 = (-W^3 + 4W^2 + 8W)/12 .\,$
The equation now is
$\, 0 = 2W(1+W)( -y^2 + 4x^3 - g_2x - g_3), \,$ where
$$\, g_2 = \frac{12(W^4 - 8W^3 + 16W + 16)}{W^2(W^2 - 4W - 8)^2},
  \quad g_3 = \frac{8(W^4 - 8W^3 - 8W - 8)}{W^3(W^2 - 4W - 8)^2}. $$
In our case of $\, W=13 \,$ these invariants become
$\, g_2 = 134508/2007889, \, g_3 = 86984/26102557. \,$
There is a $2$-torsion point $\, (-1/13,0). \,$ There is a generator point
$\, (-97/1417, 168 \sqrt{-3}/1417^{3/2}). \,$
After noticing the $1417$ in the denominators, we can scale $\,x,y\,$ to simplify the equation. After scaling it is
$\, 0 = -y^2 + 4x^3 - 134508x - 9481256, \,$ with generator point
$\, (-97, 168 \sqrt{-3}). \,$

---

This is the [elliptic curve with LMFDB label 8190.bw4](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/8190/bw/4) which has no rational generator.